# Button placed into <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate> of DataGrid does not fill all available space

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have such a `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">                       
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdPerson}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>                        
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
             <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Button Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text = "Hello"/>
             <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" IsChecked="True" />
           </Grid>                            
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>                   
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

However, the controls(`Button, TextBlock, CheckBox`) are not stretched inside of `<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate/>`.

What I have know:

[image]

How can I make all controls inside of `<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate/>` to be stretched on the whole length of `<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate/>`?

Comment: You have a good answer to solve the problem below here, but if you want to know the reason, it is that the Container in which the Header template you set is put is not a stretched control, it is probably a Stack Panel or another control adapting the size to that of its content and not to that of the container ;o) Ok is confusing but HTH

Comment: @Sabrina_cs I've tried to use StackPanel, however it is not resizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set something like this.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```